# Prestashop form submit jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prestashop

I try to submit my form with .submit() in jquery but not working because the Tools::isSubmit() method on PrestaShop wait a input with a correct name.

Here is my html form :

```
<form onsubmit="" action="{$link->getModuleLink('jmarketplace', 'addproduct', array(), true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" method="post" class="std" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The php:

```
 If (Tools::isSubmit('submitAddProduct')) {  
        //d($_POST);
        // my stuff
 }
```

So its work only with a button:

```
<button type="submit" name="submitAddProduct">
```

I want to submit this form with jquery or ajax call.
With ajax I tried this but not working, I think that Tools::isSubmit('submitAddProduct') is waiting for true param and I don't know how to do it.

This is `isSubmit` method of `Tools` class:

```
public static function isSubmit($submit)
{
    return (
        isset($_POST[$submit]) || isset($_POST[$submit.'_x']) ||     isset($_POST[$submit.'_y'])
        || isset($_GET[$submit]) || isset($_GET[$submit.'_x']) || isset($_GET[$submit.'_y'])
    );
}
```

Here is my js code with ajax call :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var form = $('.std');
    form.submit(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: baseDir + 'module/jmarketplace/addproduct',
            data : {
            //required parameters
                ajax: 1 ,
                action : 'submitAddProduct',
            },
        });
        //e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Tools::isSubmit()` checks if that param is posted or not, so you have to edit your js code like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var form = $('.std');
    form.submit(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: baseDir + 'module/jmarketplace/addproduct',
            data : {
            //required parameters
                ajax: 1 ,
                action : 'submitAddProduct',
                submitAddProduct : true // or 1
            },
        });
    //e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

However I'll suggest you to bind the event to a button.

For example:

```
<form>
    ...
    <button id="submitmyform" type="button">Send</button>
    ...
</form>
```

And the js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#submitbutton', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: baseDir + 'module/jmarketplace/addproduct',
            data : {
            //required parameters
                ajax: 1 ,
                action : 'submitAddProduct',
                submitAddProduct : true // or 1
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function(json){
                // check the page response
                console.log(json);
            };
        });
    });
});
```

Please read also this previous answers that will be very usefully for you:

- [Adding Javascript code to specific pages using Prestashop Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40372552/adding-javascript-code-to-specific-pages-using-prestashop-module/40376325#40376325)
- [Add token to ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945551/prestashop-add-a-token-to-ajax-file/40946781#40946781)

Comment: just tried and its the same the page reload like the form is gonna get submitted but I have no error if empty field it's just a refresh ??

Comment: Because you have commented the `e.preventDefault()` snippet.